# Any idea how reproduce this Android button

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-button

Thanks in advance for your time.

I would like to reproduce this android button but unfortunately I spent hours to figure out and no results!

IMAGE : https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0mSw.jpg

PS : I WANT JUST THE ICON/BACKGROUND on the left and TITLE on the right, no need for the fact counter.

If you have any idea guys please feel free to help me.

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that you've tried?

Comment: Have you tried replicating the design in xml, and attaching button listeners to the layout? How far have you gotten? Have you installed a eclipse/android studio? Or are you just not sure how of what ratios to use in the layout?

Comment: @jasonwarford I've tried the LinearLayout with the android:drawableLeft and android:background pointed to another xml style file to produce a nice flat button you can check the results here : http://i.imgur.com/6dzCW9J.jpg take a lock of the code here : http://i.imgur.com/SCQiJol.jpg

Comment: @EricS. Thanks for your comment, I am not sure if I should use ImageView and Button in each LinearLayout or anything else. I am a little bit new to Android and I would like if you can get any idea how to reproduce this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `RelativeLayout` as simple as that

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/icon"
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:padding="24dp"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="Button text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! The idea is great but i think I must figure out more, And here's the results http://i.imgur.com/HYTpSTZ.jpg. I hope i can figure out how to code with it!